# How do I load an elixir library in a simple elixir script?

Tags: elixir

In ruby scripts, I could simply do:

```rb
require 'some-gem'

SomeGem.do_something!
```

**How can I do something similar in elixir `exs` scripts without creating a brand new mix project?** So far I've searched google on ways to do this, and read a few blog posts ([such as this](https://blog.crypto-keupone.eu/an-iex-shell-with-preloaded-libraries.html)), but can't figure out a proper (read 'simple') way to do this.

*Specifically, I want to use [`HTTPoison`](https://github.com/edgurgel/httpoison) in my elixir script.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Mix.install`](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.html#install/2), introduced in Elixir 1.12.  It works in scripts, no Mix project required.

```elixir
# Install the dependencies you want directly in the script
Mix.install([:httpoison])

# Call modules from installed libraries
HTTPoison.get("https://stackoverflow.com/")
```

Comment: This is the right answer for recent Elixir versions!

Answer (score 6):

There are no global package installs in Elixir like there are in Ruby. While it might be technically possible to compile the dependencies into `.beam` files and add them to the load path of your scripts (like the article you linked to does), if you want behavior somewhat similar to Ruby, I would recommend you to make use of `mix run` to run arbitrary scripts with all the project dependencies loaded.

Create one global `mix` project with all the dependencies you want specified in `mix.exs`, write your code in any `.exs` file (doesn't have to be in the same folder), and execute it by

```
cd /path/to/mix/project && mix run /path/to/.exs
```

You could even create a wrapper shell script to automatically do the above by just invoking `my-elixir script.exs`.

(I regularly do this while testing code for answers here on StackOverflow which use some common dependencies like HTTPoison and/or Poison.)

Comment: You should update your answer, Elixir 1.12 now allows to use `Mix.install` in scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Without mix, this could be a little complex, but doable.

I think you have to explicitly adding the path where `HTTPoison` is compiled on the top of your exs script.

Elixir provides an API `Code.expand_path` to prepend a path to the beginning of the Erlang VM code path list. You could find more description about the API [here](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Code.html#prepend_path/1).

Answer (score -1):

By using `erun`, you can virtually install global Mix packages.

https://github.com/s417-lama/erun