# How do I include module from deps and use it in elixir?

Tags: elixir

I want to use module `HTTPoison`. How do I use it?

My `mix.exs` file:

```
defmodule Api.MixProject do
  use Mix.Project

  def project do
    [
      app: :api,
      version: "0.1.0",
      elixir: "~> 1.6",
      start_permanent: Mix.env() == :prod,
      deps: deps()
    ]
  end

  def application do
    [
      application: [:httpoison]
    ]
  end

  defp deps do
    [
      {:httpoison, "~> 1.0"}
    ]
  end
end
```

I tried to import it inside a module:

```
defmodule Api do
  use HTTPoison

  def hello do
    :hello
  end
end
```

...but it throws an error:

> ** (UndefinedFunctionError) function HTTPoison.__using__/1 is undefined or private

Is there a way to make it a global package and import it to just `exs` file without creating whole project?

Comment: Module names are case sensitive. Try `import HTTPoison`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And have a look at the [GitHub docs](https://github.com/edgurgel/httpoison#wrapping-httpoisonbase), you might find it useful for creating your own APIs. For example:

```
defmodule Api do
  use HTTPoison.Base

  def hello do
    :hello
  end
end
```

Comment: I think in my case it was lack of `.Base` part

Answer (score 2):

Without `import` or `use`, it seems that `HTTPoison` works as long as you specify `HTTPpoison` as a deps (like you did). I tried, with this function:

```
defmodule API do
    def start, do: HTTPoison.start |> IO.inspect
end
```

in the `iex -S mix`:

```
iex(3)> API.start
{:ok, []}
{:ok, []}
```

You can put `use HTTPoison.Base` if you want to wrap some function of `HTTPoison` in your own API as @IgorDrozdov explained.

For the last part of your question, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37684032/7852283) from @Dogbert, I could not find a better solution: it is a workaround, **there are no off-the-shelf command that allows you to import an external lib** like require does in ruby scripts for example.